# Override the replace prompt in a SaveFileDialog

Tags: .net, wpf

I am using a `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` to display a save file dialog box in a WPF application. I would like to display either a custom window, or en extra button on the prompt for replacing a file, to give the user the option of appending instead of replacing.

I know this is possible, because Microsoft Word does this. How can I achieve something similar in WPF? I am not averse to using `DllImport`s, if that is what it takes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizing the shell dialogs is a tricky thing to do, but it is getting feasible to no longer support Windows XP.  Vista and up had a drastic redesign for those dialogs, one benefit is that customizing the dialog got to be a lot easier.  Albeit from native code.  The [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) however has very decent managed wrappers for the IFileDialogCustomize COM interface.  You'll find them in the Shell\CommonFileDialogs subdirectory.

Comment: If you want to customise an xp dialog you need a resource template which is a little harder to achiev from managed code.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I am _not_ very interested in dead and dying technologies...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article about how to extend the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx

Hope this can put you on the right track.

Comment: Could this sample also work for the new dialogs in Windows Vista/7? On testing, it pops up the annoying, old style file dialogs. I would really like the new version when supported.

Comment: I'm not sure. Your question just reminded me of that article so I googled it up for you.