# Looking for a PInvoke style way to customise the SaveFileDialog using System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to write an implementation of `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog` extending from `System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog` and using the `bool RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)` method to register a custimisation hook.

I [used George Mihaescu's 2007 article on extending the print dialog](http://abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=89) for a similar use-case where I needed to add controls to the print dialog as a basis for printing but extended the example somewhat, I effectively want to use the same approach to saving.

I can't seem to find much information on the structures and extensions available, in particular I can't find the equivelant of the `PRINTDLG` structure. The closest I've found is the [MSDN article on the Common Item Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724675/override-the-replace-prompt-in-a-savefiledialog In short the suggestion from Hans is to use Vista's [`IFileDialogCustomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775912.aspx) rather than 2k/XP dialog templates. If you can go this route it is way easier.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll check this one out, could possibly be easier than the strategy I thought I would be using.

Comment: Turns out this may be a bit of work actually. One control I need to add is a custom `TreeView` that we have for a WinForms app, I used the same one on the print dialog, I also want it positioned to the right which it doesn't look like positioning is supported. I could give it a go but I think this approach will be much more work than the PInvoke method.

Comment: poking a tree view onto a common dialog is just bad form no matter how you do it. Consider an alternative UI.

Comment: David, this tree does serve a purpose and is in its rightful place on the dialog. From the print dialog which is similar: http://i.imgur.com/ipoNn.png. The dialog is to allow user selection of what to save into a PDF, and is also replicated on a similar email dialog. The alternative is to have a custom dialog with a "browse for file" option, but that means two dialogs are required when only one is needed.

Comment: I must agree that changing the default dialogs that every application is allowed to use is in poor taste.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article detailing how to extend the common file dialogs, save in particular, through Win32 API.  I've basically followed this example in my extended open and save dialog implementations.  I've simply added an additional text box below the file type combo box.

My implementation is closed source so I cannot share it.  However, I've have no issues running this code on Win2k through Win7 (x86 or x64).

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/getsavefilename.aspx

Comment: Big downside is that you end up with the ugly legacy dialogs on Vista/7

Comment: Ugly closed source solutions are bad :$

Comment: We all have to have a day job... yeah, and it is ugly - no doubt.  Been running this implementation since I was developing on XP but now that I'm aware of `IFileDialogCustomize` I'll be looking at that option to support Vista/7.